# How do I update an object in Post Model from the User Model using Mongoose, Node.js and React.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am still on this issue and I have implemented so far what I have seen online, still not working. I have two models named: PostSchema and UserSchema. PostSchema and Userschema both have a field called 'username'. So, I have created action that enables the user to update their profile. The challenge I have now is that the update made by the user which is stored in the UserSchema does not reflect on the PostSchema. For instance, I would like the username on the PostSchema to be updated to the current username on the UserSchema was the user updates or change their name from the UserSchema. I am trying to use the ref and populate features in mongoose. Probably, I am not doing it the right way.
With the current codes I have now, the posts are not fetching. If I remove the  populate(' username', 'username').exec() line, it will fetch but the post.username will not change to user.username coming from the UserSchoma model.

Here are my codes:
I am still new and still learning, kindly help me pass this stage.

**UserSchema model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose

 const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username:{  //I want the username here to update to post model too
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profilePicture:{
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
 }, {timestamps: true}
);
//exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**PostSchema model**

```
  const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
   
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    postPhoto:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },
    username:{ //this should reference user.username
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
    categories:{
        type: Array,
        required: false
        
    },
   
  }, {timestamps: true}
  );
 //exporting this schema
  module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

**This is where I am getting the posts**

```
//Get Post
 router.get("/:id", async(req, res)=>{
 try{
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    
    populate(' username', 'username').exec()
      
    res.status(200).json(post)

 }catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
 }
})
```

**This is the client side code with React.js where I called the posts from the api**

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

export default function SinglePost() {
const location = useLocation()
const path = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
const [post, setPost] = useState({});
const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
const [updateMode, setUpdateMode] = useState(false)


 useEffect(() => {
    
   const getPost = async () => {
       try{
        const response = await axios.get("/posts/"+path )
        setPost(response.data);
        setTitle(response.data.title);
        setDescription(response.data.description);
        setPostUser(response.data.username)


       }catch(err){

       }
   
   };       
 return getPost()
}, [path]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$lookup` and aggregation
aggregate object is like this

```
Post.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: req.params.id } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "User",
          localField: "username",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "username",
        },
      },
    ]).exec()
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Where will I place this code?

Comment: on collection `User` use aggregate, now I update my answer